# How to enable/disable a global filter for repository methods in Spring Data Jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In my project, all the domain classes have a `boolean voided` field, to manage the soft delete. Problem is, for all the repository methods, I had to manually override the `@Query` with `voided = false`, to get the active entries.

Is there a filtering mechanism in Spring Data JPA to define globally?

For example if the filter is enable, then `repository.findAll()`; should return all entities with `voided = false`. If filter is disabled it will return all the data without considering voided.

Comment: How are you dealing with the actual delete action now? For example, when someone call `repository.delete(yourEntity)`, or removing an entity from OneToMany with deleteOrphan ?

Comment: btw, for your entities, you may add a `@Where()` to automatically append sql snippet for all your query... not sure if it solves your problem though.  Personally I will simply create a view in DB to show non-void data

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found so far is to use filter inside @Query in the repository against every find method.